# Host Win32 window inside HWNDHost

Tags: wpf, winapi

I want to host Win32 window in WPF window to avoid flickering of DirectX content during window resizing.

Could someone say what is correct way to do this? And need I worry about DPI and something else?
And how to apply hwndhost to WPF window after that?

Could someone help with it, please? I didn`t find any normal code sample for this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bit late, but I think this StackOverflow answer will solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17471534/1628916

In HwndHost.BuildWindowCore, create a window which includes the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` style. This is called `_hwndHost` in the linked answer. Then, set your Win32 window as a child of the `_hwndHost` window.